# Image in WPF XAML truncating

Tags: wpf, image, truncation

I am trying to load an image in WPF XAML but it is getting truncated from the right.
Here is the style i used:

```
<Style x:Key="PhotoStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
    <Setter Property="StretchDirection" Value="Both" />
</Style>
```

I tried various combinations of " Stretch" and "StretchDirection" but no luck.
Please help!

Thanks in advance!

The following style actually worked:

```
<Style x:Key="PhotoStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
    <Setter Property="StretchDirection" Value="Both" />
</Style>
```

I detected a code in my huge project where this style was being overridden.
Thank you guys for your precious time!!

Comment: Did you try with all the `Stretch` types.. also post the image how it is truncated...


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry i won't be able to upload the image as SO is not allowing me to do so.Yes i tried all "Stretch" types

Comment: Still you facing the issue?

Comment: Yes, still facing the issue